# UIButton affecting UICollectionViewCell Appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Ok, I have a `ViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView` and a `UIButton`. The Button is **Not** inside the collection view. When a user taps on an item in the `UICollectionView` I have some code that changes the background color of a `UIView` in the cell to show that it is selected. I have similar code for the `UIButton` which changes its background color when a user taps it, so it is acting like a styled checkbox.

The issue I am seeing is when I tap an item in the collection view, it highlights as it should. But then if I tap on the button, the button highlights normally but the collection view changes which item is highlighted. Even though the button that was tapped is not inside the collection view and has no ties to the collection view.

See following images:
first image: I have tapped on an item in the collection view, see the item is highlighted as normal.

second image: Notice, here, when I tap the Im not sure button, the collectionview changes and the highlight goes to a different cell. But no code in the DidSelectCellForItemAt is running

[image]

[image]

```
import Foundation

class SchedulingVisitForViewController: SchedulingViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var continueButton: RoundedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var notSureButton: RoundedButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var notSureButtonTop: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var collectionData = [[String: String]]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.appointment = fetchAppointment()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionData.append([
            "image": "regularExam",
            "text": "Regular Exam",
            "data": "regular_exam"])
        self.collectionData.append([
            "image": "vaccines",
            "text": "Essential Vaccines",
            "data": "vaccines"])
        self.collectionData.append([
            "image": "meds",
            "text": "Parasite Meds",
            "data": "preventitive_meds"])
        self.collectionData.append([
            "image": "dog",
            "text": "My pet is sick",
            "data": "sick_pet"])

        self.notSureButton.layer.shadowColor = Constants.appColor.gray.light.cgColor
        self.notSureButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        self.notSureButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        self.notSureButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        self.notSureButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: self.collectionView.frame.origin.x, y:  self.collectionView.frame.origin.y, width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(2 * 170))
        self.notSureButtonTop.constant = CGFloat(2 * 170) + 20.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.collectionData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SelectVisitForCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectVisitForCollectionViewCell
        let item = indexPath.item

        cell.displayContent(image: UIImage(named: self.collectionData[item]["image"]!)!, text: self.collectionData[item]["text"]!)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SelectVisitForCollectionViewCell {
            var categories = self.appointment?.categories
            if let index = categories!.index(of: self.collectionData[indexPath.item]["data"]!) {
                categories?.remove(at: index)
                cell.showSelected(false)
            } else {
                categories?.append(self.collectionData[indexPath.item]["data"]!)
                cell.showSelected(true)
            }

            self.appointment?.categories = categories!

            if (self.appointment?.categories.count)! > 0 {
                self.continueButton.isHidden = false
            } else {
                self.continueButton.isHidden = true
            }

            saveAppointment(data: self.appointment!)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func onNotSureButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        var categories = self.appointment?.categories
        if let index = categories!.index(of: "not_sure") {
            categories?.remove(at: index)
            self.notSureButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.notSureButton.setTitleColor(Constants.appColor.gray.dark, for: .normal)
        } else {
            categories?.append("not_sure")
            self.notSureButton.backgroundColor = Constants.appColor.yellow.main
            self.notSureButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }

        self.appointment?.categories = categories!

        if (self.appointment?.categories.count)! > 0 {
            self.continueButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            self.continueButton.isHidden = true
        }
        print(self.appointment?.categories)
        saveAppointment(data: self.appointment!)
    }

    @IBAction func onContinueButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.parentPageboy?.scrollToPage(.next, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: it would help if you could share the code... hard to diagnose the problem without some code. It could be you accidentally tied some variables together or perhaps the outlets are incorrect ?

Comment: Are you reloading the collection view when you tap the button?

Comment: Show us "I'm not sure" button action code and how you highlight tapped cell in collection view

Comment: What does saveAppointment do ? I see it is used also in collectionView, so I guess it does something on the collectionView. It should not. So, may be you could add a parameter to saveAppointment, like update: Bool ; and pass false from IBAction, true from didSelectItem. Use it in saveAppointment to skip change in CollectionView if false.

Answer (score -1):

The issue pointed out by caninster_exister is that I was reloading the collection view

Comment: It's not correct. You can reload collection view, you just need to keep some data source (since collection cells are reusable) for your collection view which says something like: *if indexPath.item is 0 color will be this*